# Is a spell considered to "end" if it is re-cast?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic

Several spells, including many of the Exalted spells, have a penalty or sacrifice that applies at the end of the spell's duration. If the spell is re-castcast before the duration ends, does the penalty apply before the second casting takes effect?

Answer (score 6):

When a spell with a duration is cast a second time, it does not end the first casting. The two spells overlap and they both take place (but their effects don't stack since they come from the same source).

Casting the spell a second time has no effect on the durtation of the first casting, that still ends (with all ill effects) when it would have before.

Comment: A couple of spells, like *haste*, do self stack, but these are exceptions rather than the rule.

Comment: @thedarkwanderer From the d20srd: "Multiple haste effects don’t stack." (http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/haste.htm) Maybe you have the wrong example?

Comment: @mike32 Alright, *polymorph any object* then.  Also any spell that grants a circumstance or dodge bonus and doesn't explicitly say it doesn't self stack.

Comment: Whether or not a spell stacks is somewhat ancillary to the question (the OP never indicated whether they were on the same target or not). What he did ask is with respect to penalties that apply when the spell's duration ends.

Comment: @wyrmwood Well if it's on different targets it's even more "why do you think it ends?"

Answer (score 4):

No. Unless there's some specific restriction for a given spell, or you are doing something special like holding the charge, casting the same spell a second time before the first spell's duration has completed has no effect on the first spell's duration.